# How can I check whether the device is connected to a Power supply, USB or to a Dock

Tags: android

I'm developing an application in which I want to check like to which power source my device is connected to? I know it is possible by some way but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks for helping.

Comment: take a look at the [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) it might help you more with varieties of options to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what information you're after a BatteryManager intent may be more useful.

Make a class extending BroadcastReceiver.

Make an intent filter for Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

registerReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   TextView ctl;

   int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
   switch(plugged)
   {
      case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC:
          break;
      case BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB:
          break;
      default:
          break;
   }
}
```

Don't forget to unregisterReceiver when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a BroadcastReceiver which starts on device boot, listen for some (or all, or alternates) of these:

- CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK
- CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK
- ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED
- ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

From there you can respond however you see fit.

[Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)